# Force restarting of the Docker container using Docker Compose

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose, ansible

How to restart the Docker container using Docker Compose?

I'm using the below command to restart the Apache server, and tried running the build, it said 'changed in the Jenkins console' but it didn't work in restarting the Docker container. I have to manually restart the Docker container and then it works fine.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.yml -f docker-compose.web.production.yml up -d --build
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.yml restart
docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.production.yml restart
```

If you have strange behavior you can try restarting your docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: Can I add the below command docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.yml

Comment: Can I run by using the below two commands

docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.yml -f docker-compose.web.production.yml up -d --build

docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.yml -f docker-compose.web.production.yml restart

Comment: Well the `up` command is enough to restart the container. Add --force-recreate to ensure if your build is exactly as before it will recreate the containers. But a docker-compose restart is enough to restart the containers you don't need to rebuild the containers.

Comment: Could you please give me the exact command/commands to run. As the first command (docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.yml -f docker-compose.web.production.yml up -d --build) is building but the container is not restarting, I have to manually restart the container. Do I need to change the first command to (docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.yml -f docker-compose.web.production.yml up --force-recreate). Or do I still need to add the other two commands which you gave me.

Comment: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.yml -f docker-compose.web.production.yml up -d --build --force-recreate` But i think it is an overkill